# Make a topological search function with given depth first search function

Tags: python

I am making a stack of vertices after a topological sort. I think the code I have written is correct but I do not know how to print out the stack.
This is my code:

```
  def toposort (self):
    stack = Stack()
    top = []
    for i in range(0,len(self.Vertices)):
      self.Vertices[i].visited == False
    for i in range(0,len(self.Vertices)):
      if not (self.Vertices[i]).wasVisited():
        self.dffs(self.getIndex(i),stack)
    return stack

  def dffs(self, v, stack):
    self.Vertices[v].visited == True
    for i in range(0,len(self.Vertices)):
      if (self.adjMat[v][i] > 0) and (not (self.Vertices[i]).wasVisited()):
        self.dffs(self.getIndex(self.Vertices[i]), stack)
        print (self.Vertices[v])
    stack.push(v)
```

and the output I get is: <**main**.Stack object at 0x104adf1d0>
I'm sure it is an easy fix but I just don't know how. My graph is a bunch of vertexes and labels with weights.

```
class Stack (object):
  def __init__ (self):
    self.stack = []

  # add an item to the top of the stack
  def push (self, item):
    self.stack.append ( item )

  # remove an item from the top of the stack
  def pop (self):
    return self.stack.pop()

  # check what item is on top of the stack without removing it
  def peek (self):
    return self.stack[len(self.stack) - 1]

  # check if a stack is empty
  def isEmpty (self):
    return (len(self.stack) == 0)

  # return the number of elements in the stack
  def size (self):
    return (len(self.stack))
```

Comment: Add a `__str__()` method to `Stack`

Comment: How would I make such method?

Comment: That depends -- can you post the source for Stack?

Comment: class Stack (object):
  def __init__ (self):
    self.stack = []

  # add an item to the top of the stack
  def push (self, item):
    self.stack.append ( item )

  # remove an item from the top of the stack
  def pop (self):
    return self.stack.pop()

  # check what item is on top of the stack without removing it
  def peek (self):
    return self.stack[len(self.stack) - 1]

  # check if a stack is empty
  def isEmpty (self):
    return (len(self.stack) == 0)

  # return the number of elements in the stack
  def size (self):
    return (len(self.stack))

Comment: It's not very easy to read in a comment, is it?  Please edit your original question to include the additional code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your actual question is "how do I print my Stack object".  By default calling str() on a custom class just prints out the type name and its id, which isn't very helpful.  To print out the contents instead, add the `__str__()` method to Stack:

```
def __str__(self):
   return str(self.stack)
```